# How to dial a number programatically in BlackBerry 10 Webworks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm able to dial a number with this function:

```
blackberry.invoke.invoke({
    uri: "tel:55555"
}, onSuccess, onError);
```

Unfortunately, my app is made to dial USSD codes and when using USSD number, I got this message in the simulator: "USSD dialing from URI is not allowed". Is there a function that allows dialing USSD code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately BlackBerry WebWorks does not support USSD calls, neither has API to solve this task.

Comment: What about Native SDK?

Comment: @IsmaelToé Native API supports USSD cals. Here is [the link for legacy  ,BB OS 7.x and older os-es, java API example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/calling-USSD-commands-via-BB-api/td-p/511934) and here is [the link to a post related to the USSD on BB 10 platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443733/how-to-use-ussd-in-blackberry-app-new-to-bb-cascades)